# how to connect mysql master outside of k8s

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, dbeaver

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/
deployed a replicated MySQL topology.
The doc says:
That client service is used to connect to any MySQL instance for reads.
For writes, you must instead connect to the primary: mysql-0.mysql.
I can connect to the master: mysql-0.mysql **in k8s**.

But how to connect to the master: mysql-0.mysql **outside of k8s for writes** with DBeaver tool?

I hope to manipulate mysql with DBeaver for convenience.

I could use it to query data with "A-Worker-IP:NodePort". If I created a db with the same way, the db could only be seen in one node, not in other 2 nodes(1 master and 2 slaves).

Comment: Could you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57428781/11560878) from a similar question?

Comment: I'm using a Kubernetes cluster in other machines. I couldn't use `localhost` as a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

> I could use it to query data with "A-Worker-IP:NodePort". If I created a db with the same way, the db could only be seen in one node, not in other 2 nodes(1 master and 2 slaves).

That's incorrect: the Node Port is performing NAT even if you're using the IP of a node where your service is running thanks to the `iptables` S/DNAT.

This behavior can be disabled using the `externalTrafficPolicy=Local`.